# unable to export .apk from eclipse

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

Tried to export working android project from eclipse. The screen is frozen at page "Export Android Application". "Next" button is grayed out. Same project runs fine on emulator and HTC as well. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse but if that doesn't fix it, try the following:

Under the Project menu, choose Clean...

Click Clean All Projects then click on OK.

I sometimes find that Eclipse gets messed up. Cleaning all projects in my current workspace usually takes care of it.